# Same self-signed cert used by both server and client (curl with --cacert) but https fetch still fails?

Tags: curl, openssl, ssl-certificate, tls1.2, self-signed

I followed various tutorials and stackoverflow questions to learn how to create a self-signed certificate, ensuring it had server alt names, use it to configure https for an express server, and successfully make requests against the server from a browser (after adding the certificate as a trusted cert to the browser).

I re-downloaded the cert as follows:
`openssl s_client -showcerts -servername mydevserver -connect mydevserver:443 </dev/null`

And then I copied the text between 'begin certificate' and 'end certificate' to `/etc/ssl/thecert.crt`

Using commandline tools to hit the same https endpoint doesn't work, eg:
`curl -v --cacert "/etc/ssl/thecert.crt" -H "Content-Type: application/json"  https://mydevserver:443/api`

I can see curl using the cacert in the verbose output but it still complains:
`SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate`

- Is the certificate itself just configured wrong (if so, how come the browser accepts it)?
- What else am I missing?

Comment: Did the text you copied *include* the `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and end lines or did you just copy what was between it?  You need those include lines.  curl's --cacert option should allow it to verify if you are specifying the self signed cert.

Comment: @drew010 - yes  i did include the `---begin---` and `---end---` lines...

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the certificate being self-signed was not sufficient to make it "trustworthy". It needed to be signed by a certificate authority.

1. I had to first create my own certificate authority (CA) using a
   self-signed certificate, and then use that resulting certificate to
   sign a brand new CSR / certificate for the server in question.
2. Then, once the CA cert is added to the local CA store, curl doesn't
   even need the --cacert parameter anymore; like other https clients
   it can validate the certificate received from the server, because it
   will say signed by my CA, which is trusted on the local machine.

Hope this helps someone.